# En código Javascript no se puede invocar la segunda instancia del objeto sino solo la primera ¿por que?

Tags: javascript

En este código trato de llamar los 2 objetos instanciados a partir de GeneradorProductos, pero me toma solo el primer objeto, que es el de leggin rojo y no logro encontrar el por qué...

```js
class GeneradorProductos {
        constructor(usuario) {
            this.nombre = usuario.name
            this.genero = usuario.genero
            this.precio = usuario.precio
        }
    }

    let productos = new GeneradorProductos (
        {name: "leggin rojo" , genero: "femenino" , precio: 830},
        {name: "jean azul" , genero: "masculino", precio: 3000 })

    const baseDeDatos = [] //ListadoDeProductos

    baseDeDatos.push(productos)

    console.log(productos);

    let CantidadDeProductos = Number(prompt ("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE PRENDAS"))

    const ValorProducto = baseDeDatos.map( (ropa) => {
        return {
            nombre: ropa.nombre,
            precio: ropa.precio * CantidadDeProductos,
            genero: ropa.genero
        }
    })

    console.log(ValorProducto);

    const TotalProductos = ValorProducto.reduce ((acum , elemento) => acum + elemento.precio,0 )

    console.log(`El total a pagar es $ ${TotalProductos}`);
```

Comment: No conozco esa sintaxis para instanciar dos objetos sobre la misma variable.... tenes documentacion al respecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```js
class GeneradorProductos {
    constructor(usuario) {
        this.nombre = usuario.name
        this.genero = usuario.genero
        this.precio = usuario.precio
    }
}

let productos = [
  new GeneradorProductos ({name: "leggin rojo" , genero: "femenino" , precio: 830}),
  new GeneradorProductos ({name: "jean azul" , genero: "masculino", precio: 3000 })
  ]

const baseDeDatos = [] //ListadoDeProductos

// baseDeDatos.push(productos)

// console.log(productos)

// console.log(baseDeDatos)

let CantidadDeProductos = Number(prompt ("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE PRENDAS"))

const ValorProducto = productos.map( (ropa) => {
        
    return {
        nombre: ropa.nombre,
        precio: ropa.precio * CantidadDeProductos,
        genero: ropa.genero
    }
})

console.log(ValorProducto);

const TotalProductos = ValorProducto.reduce ((acum , elemento) => acum + elemento.precio,0 )

console.log(`El total a pagar es $ ${TotalProductos}`);
```

**Explicación:**

Dada la clase dada `GeneradorProductos`, el argumento que espera el *constructor* es solo un objeto, no dos, por lo tanto lo más conveniente, visto el resto del código, ha sido crear un *array* de productos invocando a la clase en cada elemento, de este modo:

```javascript
let productos = [
  new GeneradorProductos ({name: "leggin rojo" , genero: "femenino" , precio: 830}),
  new GeneradorProductos ({name: "jean azul" , genero: "masculino", precio: 3000 })
]
```

Con eso conseguimos ya crear un array de objetos de esa clase, la cual podemos usar directamente en el `map`, donde antes se pretendia usar la constante `baseDeDatos`, que ya no tiene ninguna utilidad en este contexto. Por lo tanto el otro cambio realizado es:

```javascript
const ValorProducto = productos.map( (ropa) => {
```

donde se ha sustituido `baseDeDatos` por el array `productos`.

Comment: Si, considero que resuelve lo que quiero...

Comment: Perfecto pues. Me alegro que te sirva. He agregado un poco de explicación para que conste.